# How to properly use setPatternOffset to fix NSColor colorWithPatternImage insanity

Tags: cocoa, drawing, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to draw a tiled pattern inside a NSScrollView which is itself inside a resizable window (on Mac OS X).  The code simply calls [NSColor colorWithPatternImage], CGContextSetFillColorWithColor, and CGContextFillRect.

The problem is that the pattern is drawn relative to the bottom-left corner of the window.  This is documented behavior, but causes two unpleasant effects:

1. When the window is resized, the pattern scrolls up or down in a very surprising manner.
2. When the scroll view is scrolled, and then scrolled back, the newly drawn pattern doesn't line up with the scrolled (buffered) part of the pattern.

I'm able to mostly fix problem 2 by calling CGContextConvertPointToDeviceSpace, passing in 0,0, and seeing what I get back -- this tells me my scroll offset, which I can then use with CGContextSetPatternPhase to fix the problem.  (Though it doesn't completely fix it -- when I scroll quickly, I still see mismatched patterns, for reasons I haven't sorted out yet.)

But addressing problem 1 is proving really thorny.  From my drawing code, which only knows the CGContext, I can't find any way to get the window height.  (The Device/User space conversion routines seem completely unaffected by window height.)

Short of adding a bunch of plumbing to all the drawing code to pass around a window reference, is there any way to figure out the correct offset so that my pattern will stay put when the window is resized, and scroll properly when the scrollview is scrolled?

Answer (score 0):

Oops -- shortly after posting this, I found at least a partial answer: the current transformation matrix (from CGContextGetCTM) reflects both the window height, and the scroll offset.

(Or at least, it does in my app; I set the CTM very early in the pipeline to give me a top-down coordinate system so I can use much the same code on iOS.)

So, if I just call CGContextGetCTM, and then pass the .x0 and .y0 values of the result to CGContextSetPatternPhase, it mostly works.

I'm still running into some visual glitches when I scroll quickly horizontally, though not vertically -- a very odd effect, which suggests to me that it might be something in my code, or perhaps related to how wide the content area is.  I'll dig further.

Comment: This may or may not be relevant, but if you are trying to get the pattern to be placed in the same position even while scrolling is occurring, then you may want to look into setting `NSClipView.copiesOnScroll = NO` (NSClipView is usually the direct subview of NSScrollView). The default of `copiesOnScroll = YES` will cause the scroll-drawing code to efficiently shift the pattern as scrolling occurs, which may not be what you want.